# django ajax project- basket - collecting values in array

Tags: django, ajax

in my Django store I have a basket which in views.py has the class:

```
class BasketAddView(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        basket = Basket(request)
        product_id = str(request.POST.get('productid'))    
        product_size = str(request.POST.get('productsize'))
        product_qty = str(request.POST.get('productqty'))
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id) #it was id and should be p
        basket_size_table = []
        basket_size_table.append(product_size)
        basket.add(product=product, size=product_size, qty = product_qty)
        basketqty=basket.__len__()
        response = JsonResponse({'size': basket_size_table,'product' : product_id, 'qty': basketqty, }) 
        return response
```

web inspector in output in console show that I have only last size in array:
[[image]] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD2xT.png)

but I would like to have a collections of sizes in one array.
Product_size is a single element, in html it is a select field with different values. I wish I could add these individual values ​​to the list of  product with the same id but different sizes, example : product:"6"
qty: 2
size: ['8/ϕ15mm/US5','7/ϕ14mm/US6']

Comment: You're appending only one value inside your **basket_size_table** list if you want a collection of it then you've to append multiple values.

Comment: but how to do that ?

Comment: Hello @hebel.dev can you provide some expected output ny making [edit] to your question and also you're getting product size from client using `.get()` which will return you single element if you want to access a list of sizes then send it  string like this `"['size1','size2'...]"` and inside you view convert it to list using `list(my_sizes)`

Comment: for example when i do something like this ` basket_size_table = list(product_size)` the output is one string(only one size') divided by individual signs.